# Getting unexpected output from NSDateComponents

Tags: ios, nsdate

After comparing two dates (`currentDate` and `_timerStartDate`) I get the following output

```
nstimeinterval: 88.998212
2014-05-14 14:07:08.284  currentDate: 14-05-2014 14:07:08
2014-05-14 14:07:08.284  stopDate: 14-05-2014 14:05:39
2014-05-14 14:07:08.284  hour: 10
```

This is correct and expected. However when I break `timerDate` down I get 10 hours from the NSLog...I'm expecting zero. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_timerStartDate];
NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];


NSLog(@"nstimeinterval: %f", timeInterval);

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSLog(@"currentDate: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate]);
NSLog(@"stopDate: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_timerStartDate]);


NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: ( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:timerDate];
NSLog(@"year: %li", (long)components.year);


NSLog(@"timer: %@", timeString);

timerTicksForCounter = timeString;

NSLog(@"hour: %li", (long)components.hour);
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about the intent of some of these API. If all you want is to quantify the difference between two dates, you can use the `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` method, a la: `[calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:_timerStartDate toDate:currentDate options:0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it you're actually trying to accomplish? To populate an `NSDateComponents` with the time elapsed between two dates? In that case, you probably want `-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]`, with the from-date being your start, and the to-date being the current date when you stop. In the mean time, you seem to be doing a lot of complicated and possibly unnecessary mashing of dates together.